# Jenkinsのp4-pluginにてワークスペースのCharacter Setにshiftjisを使うとエラーになります

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins 2.80、P4 Plugin 1.75を使用しています。
JenkinsのP4PluginにてCharacterSetにshiftjisが使用できない問題を教えていただきたいと思います。

以下、詳細です。

Jenkinsのソースコードの管理にてPerforce Softwareを選択し、以下の様にCharacter Setに「shiftjis」を設定しています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この状態でビルドを実行すると「P4-ShiftJISはサポートしてません」というエラーが発生します。

```html
SCMのポーリングが実行
ビルドします。 ワークスペース: C:\Jenkins\workspace\Project
... p4 client -o jenkins_Project
 +
... p4 info
 +
FATAL: P4-ShiftJIS
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: P4-ShiftJIS
 at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
 at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.setCharsetName(Server.java:751)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.client.ClientHelper.clientLogin(ClientHelper.java:129)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.client.ClientHelper.<init>(ClientHelper.java:108)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.tasks.AbstractTask.getConnection(AbstractTask.java:208)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.tasks.AbstractTask.setWorkspace(AbstractTask.java:80)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.PerforceScm.checkout(PerforceScm.java:426)
 at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
```

文字化けしてしまいますが他の文字コード（UTF8など）ではファイルの取得はできています。

Perforceから直接ファイルの取得を行うと、文字コードshiftjisで取得できています。

Javaの問題だとは思いますが、あまり詳しくないので、ご協力の程よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `shiftjis`以外の文字列(例えば、`test`)を入力すると、どのような例外のスタックトレース出力されますか？

Comment: >Kohei TAMURA様　入力がリスト形式で固定のため、testなどのリストにない文字列を確認することができませんでした。リストにある文字列は全て試してみましたが、shiftjis以外で例外が発生するものはありませんでした。

Comment: であるとすれば、バグの可能性が高いですね。ソースコードのどこかにshiftjisが該当する条件だけ「P4-」という文字列を付加している箇所があるのかもしれません。Jenkins 2.80とP4 Plugin 1.75のソースコードを読んでみると、分かりそうですね。

Comment: >Kohei TAMURA様　わかりました。ソースコードの中を調べてみることにします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、P4(※このソフトウェア自体を私は使ったことないので知りませんが...)のコマンドラインツールか何かで文字セットをセットするような対応が必要なのだと思います。

時間があったので、ちょっとソースコードを見てみましたが、`com.perforce.p4java.server.PerforceCharsets()`のstaticイニシャライザーに、以下のようなマップを生成する処理がありました。

```
static {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("none", "none");
    map.put("utf8", "UTF-8");
    map.put("iso8859-1", "ISO-8859-1");
    map.put("utf16-nobom", "UTF-16");
    // shiftjis (JDK Shift_JIS charset is NOT the same as Perforce shiftjis)
    // Perforce shiftjis (MS932) is a superset of Shift_JIS (SJIS).
    // p4ToJavaCharsets.put(knownCharsets[count++], "Shift_JIS");
    // shiftjis (Perforce implementation of Microsoft code page 932)
    // P4-ShiftJIS is a charset wrapped around the JDK MS932 charset,
    // with some Perforce specific updates.
    // Note: Perforce shiftjis is suppose to be a full MS932 implementation.
    map.put("shiftjis", "P4-ShiftJIS");
    map.put("eucjp", "EUC-JP");
    map.put("winansi", "windows-1252");

    ・・・
```

このマップを使って、`shiftjis`を`P4-ShiftJIS`という独自の文字セットに変換しています。で、最終的に`Charset.forName()`の引数に`P4-ShiftJIS`を渡して、`UnsupportedCharsetException`が発生しています。

`Charset.forName()`で`UnsupportedCharsetException`がスローされるのは、`Charset`の[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName-java.lang.String-)に記載されている通り、指定された文字セットが現在のJava仮想マシンで利用できない場合です。

[このあたりのページ](https://www.toyo.co.jp/ss/contents/detail/technical_note066.html)や`p4java-2017.2.1577651-sources.jar`を解凍してソースコードを読んでみて下さい。どのような対応すべきか分かると思います。

Comment: >Kohei TAMURA様　調査ありがとうございます。情報をたよりに私の方でも該当の箇所を見つけることができました。試しにP4-ShiftJISをShiftJISに変更して再コンパイルしてみようと思います。（jarを解凍→classをjavaに逆コンパイルはできたのですが、javaをclassに再コンパイル→jarに圧縮のところで手間取ってます。）

Comment: ShiftJISに変更することで目的を満たせるのであればいいかもしれませんが、あえて`P4-Sh‌​iftJIS`に変換している意図がありそうなので、そのあたりはご注意下さい。

Comment: >Kohei TAMURA様　jarに変換して確認できました。結果は目的を満たせるものでした。P4-ShiftJISについて調べたところ、このページhttps://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/charset/PerforceShiftJISCharset.htmlにP4-ShiftJisはMS932エンコーディングを使用してるとありましたので、MS932でも試したところ、こちらも目的を満たしていました。根本的な原因はわかりませんが、現状はこちらで修正したファイルで使用しようと思います。